# Integration of NLog: Use interface with methods or with Enums?

Tags: c#, oop, nlog

To integrate NLog, we want to define an interface, and are considering two approaches.
We are using C#.

Approach 1:

```
public interface ILoggingManager
{
    void DoErrorLogging(type , string ) 
    void DoErrorLogging(type , string  , exception ) 

    void DoTraceLogging(type , string ) 
    void DoTrace Logging(type , string  , exception ) 

    // And so on for all the types that Nlog supports.
     .... 
    // Finally would have 10 methods defined in this interface. 
}
```

Approach 2:

```
//Have an Enum defined for the logging levels
public enum LoggingLevel
{
    Error,
    Warn,
    Info,
    Debug,
    Trace
}

public interface ILoggingManager
{
    void DoLogging(type , LoggingLevel , string ) 
    void DoLogging(type , LoggingLevel   , exception ) 
}
```

Questions:

1. Which is a better approach keeping design principles(like SOLID) in mind?
2. Which approach is a better approach in terms of performance?

Answer (score 0):

My answer does not provide a direct solution, but still...

I'd use an **existing** logging framework, that include all the interfaces. The rest is (or should be) configuration.

I'd suggest you to either use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [slf](http://slf.codeplex.com/)

If you insist on your own interfaces, then I think that performance is not an issue here what so ever. Either you map the enum value to the appropriate method of NLog (Approach 2), or you use it directly (Approach 1).

Approach 2 is a lot cleaner, no doubt. I'd change it a bit to:

```
public interface ILoggingManager
{
    void DoLogging(type , LoggingLevel , string, /* optional */ exception ) 
}
```

I'd describe the benefit I see in Approach 2. Sometimes you don't know up front what is the logging level you're about to use. Let's say that you're inspecting an exception. Sometimes you end up with `Warn` and sometimes you end up with `Error`. If you use Approach 2, the code reuse is simpler: just choose the relevant enum value and you're set. If you use Approach 1, code reuse might include mapping an [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) to the relevant method, and invoking it, which makes the whole thing a bit too complex for logging...

BTW, what is `type` here? the type of the consuming class?

Comment: Ron, we are going to use the Nlog framework, the log levels are mapped to NLog's log levels, just that we are writing an interface and we would like to know which is the better approach. Why is the second approach Cleaner ?

Comment: @siva, You can inspect the consuming class by reflection, but that's another story...